# $addFields for specific entry using MongoDB in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I am using the pymongo library in Python to update specific entries in my MongoDB, spesifically using the db.update_one() function which was previously working with the aggregation pipeline $set but now fails when using $addFields. I am trying to insert the entry:
`'Client Facing': ['No']`
into the object:

```
{
    'Content Format': ['Presentation'], 
    'Category': ['Systems w/TPS'], 
    'Offering Market': ['Enterprise Linux Market'], 
    'Offering Portfolio': ['Enterprise Linux'], 
    'Offering Name': ['HANA excl L Systems - POWER9 H924 Scale-Out'], 
    'Keywords': ['SAP'], 
    'Language': ['English'], 
    'Additional Information': ['prepare-atl'], 
    'Organization Owner': ['Technology'], 
    'Brand': ['Cognitive Systems'], 
    'Content Owner Group': ['Technology - Systems']
}
```

So I was using the update_one() with the parameters: **{'seismic_id': 12345}** (this is the filter), and

```
{'$addFields': {'seismic_properties_obj.Client Facing': ['No']}}
```

However, when I do this it fails with the error:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Unknown modifier: $addFields. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 9, 'errmsg': 'Unknown modifier: $addFields. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array'}
```

Comment: you can use $addFields only in update with aggregation pipeline, can you show your whole query?

Comment: @turivishal my full query is just the update_one method that looks like:
```
DB['assets'].update_one({'seismic_id': 12345}, {'$addFields': {'seismic_properties_obj.Client Facing': ['No']}})
```

Comment: as i said in first comnet $addFields is aggregation stage, you can use $set here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following snippet

```
DB['assets'].update_one(
    {'seismic_id': 12345},
    {'$set':
        {'seismic_properties_obj.Client Facing': 'No'}
    }
)
```

This will find record `seismic_id` = 12345, then add property `seismic_properties.Client Facing` and set it to `'No'`

**Note:** In this case, `$addField` is not a valid operator since its used within the aggregation framework. Instead using `$set` allows you to add/update specific keys without updating the entire document.